# iOS animation is turning sideways

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

This seems super odd to me. I want to do some animations and then display an image after.

In my viewdidload I set up the image array for the animations.

```
 self.photoView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"App-logoGIFF1.png"],
                                      ...
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"App-logoGIFF18.png"],nil];
    self.photoView.animationDuration = 2.0;
    self.photoView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    self.photoView.hidden = YES;
```

Then later I call it in a photopickerdidfinishpickingphotoorwhatevermethod. When I call it like this:

```
 [self.photoView startAnimating];
    self.photoView.image = image;
```

I see the animations but my image doesn't get displayed after.
When I try to set the image first and then animate:

```
    self.photoView.image = image;
 [self.photoView startAnimating];
```

Then I get my image to show up after, but my animation turns sideways. How odd is that? Any ideas?

Comment: I forget exactly what it's called but turn off the "Autoresize inner views" flag or whatever it's called in the view OUTSIDE your animated object.

Comment: I had high hopes, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `imageOrientation` property of the UIImages you are using.

Comment: It is, in fact, because of the imageOrientation of the photoview.image. Only problem is that I have no way to override that. When I try to run the animation and then assign the image value then the image doesn't show up

Comment: I am resizing the image before I save it to the database. The way I am resizing the image must change the imageOrientation property; when I assigned photoView.image = resizedImage instead of setting it to the original image from the imagePicker, then the animation seems to work. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yes, I've had my resizing algorithm change the imageOrientation. You're welcome.